# How to get data before Router is loaded after Auth Service using angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I hope this is not duplicated.

I have this component to Login with a user, that calls a service and gives me a Token.

When the login is success I save the token to localStorage and I get the user Data with `getUserData` service and save it to a localStorage with `saveUderData` service.

```
  onLoginSuccess(token: Token) {

    this.authService.saveToken(token);

    this.authService.getUserData().subscribe(
      userData =>  this.onGetUserDataSuccess(userData)
    );
  }

  onGetUserDataSuccess(userData: UserDataModel) {
    this.authService.saveUserData(userData);
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }
```

> The problem is that when I go to the main component the data is not
>   loaded and I have to refresh the page.

I have this in my main component.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('_UserToken') && localStorage.getItem('_UserData') && (!this.authService.userToken || !this.authService.userToken.access_token)) {
      this.authService.saveToken(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('_UserToken')));
      this.authService.saveUserData(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('_UserData')));

      this.userData = this.authService.userData;

    }
```

with `this.userData` I get the data.

I solved it in another component with `Resolve` but here I can't do it because i don't know how.

I tried this in `onLoginSuccess(token: Token)`

```
this.route.data.subscribe(
      userData => console.log(userData['user'])
    );
```

but the userData is `undefined`

here my routes.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { title: 'Inicio'}, resolve: {user: UserDataResolve},
    children: [
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: '', component: MenuComponent},
    ]},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { title: 'Iniciar Sesión'} },

];
```

and here is my Resolve

```
@Injectable()
export class UserDataResolve implements Resolve<UserDataModel> {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<UserDataModel> {
    return this.authService.getUserData();
  }

}
```

I hope you can understand me, my english is not the best. thanks =).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a getter instead of a simple property in your component:

```
get userData(): string {
    this.authService.userData;
}
```

That way any time changes are detected it will get the current userData from your service.